# I keep getting a blank black screen when I open my Ubuntu 20.04. What do I do?

Tags: 20.04

I keep getting a blank black screen when I open my Ubuntu 20.04. What do I do? I have tried to type in commands but it’s not responding

Comment: "Recovery mode" -> https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Recovery+mode